# Rider AWS Lambda Hello World project misses libhostfxr.so

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, aws-lambda, rider, aws-sam

Fresh new Rider wizard generated AWS Lambda project fails on building:

```
dima@ubu:~/proj/HelloWorld2 $ dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.808 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.302 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
dima@ubu:~/proj/HelloWorld2 $ echo $DOTNET_ROOT
/usr/bin
dima@ubu:~/proj/HelloWorld2 $ which dotnet
/usr/bin/dotnet
dima@ubu:~/proj/HelloWorld2 $ sam build
Building function 'HelloWorldFunction'
Running DotnetCliPackageBuilder:GlobalToolInstall

Tool 'amazon.lambda.tools' was reinstalled with the latest stable version (version '4.0.0').
Running DotnetCliPackageBuilder:RunPackageAction


Build Failed
Error: DotnetCliPackageBuilder:RunPackageAction - Dotnet CLI Failed: A fatal error occurred. The required library libhostfxr.so could not be found.
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [/home/dima/.dotnet/tools/.store/amazon.lambda.tools/4.0.0/amazon.lambda.tools/4.0.0/tools/netcoreapp2.1/any/].
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [/snap/bin] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [/etc/dotnet/install_location].

The .NET Core runtime can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.20.04-x64

dima@ubu:~/proj/HelloWorld2 $ find /usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr/ -name "*.so"
/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr/2.1.20/libhostfxr.so
/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr/3.1.6/libhostfxr.so
dima@ubu:~/proj/HelloWorld2 $ find /home/dima/.dotnet/tools/.store/amazon.lambda.tools/4.0.0/amazon.lambda.tools/4.0.0/tools/netcoreapp2.1/any/ -name "*.so"
dima@ubu:~/proj/HelloWorld2 $
```

UPDATE: Here is how I created the project:

[image]

Comment: Have you used the correct [dotnet CLI template](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet#dotnet-cli-templates) for lambda function?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Please see the update from above - I just used Rider UI.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't recommend to rely on your IDE UI. Even with Visual Studio it's better and more clear to use a dotnet CLI with AWS templates/tools to generate a project template and publish the app, while IDE is used for writing a code only

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Probably I need to delete this question. `dotnet lambda` fails the [same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973250/dotnet-lambda-fails-on-ubuntu).

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9304  might help